# Why the application cannot scale on high DPI screen?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm developing an application using qt on laptop with 125% scaling. I searched web ways to scale application. I'm used:

- QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=true
- QT_ENABLE_HIGHDPI_SCALING=true
- QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1
- `QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);`

No one of this ways have no effect.

`QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);` located in main function:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling); //It is here.
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

QtCreator 4.13.2, Qt 5.15.1, MSVC2019 64bit debug.

Comment: I dont know why, but after restarting qt, only QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.25 starts working. but it looks ugly and other ways keep not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm **restarted** Qt and scaling starts working. Also restart needed after edit of evironment variables.